# Suricata: nf_queue: full, dropping packets(s)

Tags: networking

I am using Suricata IDS in NFQUEUE mode:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -m mark ! --mark 0x1/0x1 -m comment --comment "Suricata NFQUEUE handler" -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0 --queue-bypass
```

Today server port became unavailable for some time, and this messages appeared in `kern.log`:

```
18:51:53 up02-lb kernel: nf_queue: full at 4096 entries, dropping packets(s)
```

How can I increase it? It is not controlled by any of sysctl parameters and I can not find it in `/proc/net/netfilter/nfnetlink_queue`. I increased `max-pending-packets` in `suricata.yaml`, but I am not sure this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value is set by Suricata. It uses "max-pending-packets" from your suricata.yaml and multiplies it by 4

```
int r = NFQInitThread(ntv, (max_pending_packets * NFQ_BURST_FACTOR));
if (r != TM_ECODE_OK) {
```

Where NFQ_BURST_FACTOR is 4. See https://github.com/inliniac/suricata/blob/71a3c4caac22b475c09ee2f082f11d443dc02cc0/src/source-nfq.c#L712

You can increase the value in your suricata.yaml. If you set max-pending-packets to 4096, you should get output similar to:

```
[6146] 7/6/2016 -- 20:31:12 - <Info> -- binding this thread 0 to queue '0'
[6146] 7/6/2016 -- 20:31:12 - <Info> -- setting queue length to 16384
```

Another thing you could try is enabling the 'fail open' support. This means that on the kernel side, NFQ is passing packets when Suricata can't keep up. This leads to a security risk though, as some packets won't be inspected.

From the suricata.yaml:

```
# On linux >= 3.6, you can set the fail-open option to yes to have the kernel
# accept the packet if suricata is not able to keep pace.
nfq:
#  mode: accept
#  repeat-mark: 1
#  repeat-mask: 1
#  route-queue: 2
#  batchcount: 20
#  fail-open: yes
```

If you uncomment the last open the fail-open support will be enabled.

I definitely recommend increasing the queue length before enabling fail-open though.